# How do I invert media query?

Tags: css

How can I select the opposite of the following media query?

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { }
```

almost as if I were saying (pseudocode of course)

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
....
} else {
....
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `not`

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries

```
@media not screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { ... }
```